# Open a gnome terminal through a bash script and call and run an aliased command

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnome-terminal

I am trying to write a bash script that opens a new gnome terminal window and runs an aliased command. I have seen that instead of using aliases using a function is the proper way to go. I have tried both approaches but I can't get it to work though, as I am getting an error that the command is not recognized.

This is what I have.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Cluster related functions
function gateway () {
    ssh user@something -t ssh gateway
}

gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Bash -- bash -c "gateway; bash;"
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
bash: gateway: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to export the function before calling `gnome-terminal`:

```
export -f gateway
```

Notes:

- You cannot export aliases.
- Exporting functions is not a portable feature. It will work from `bash` to `bash`.
- It will naturally work if the new `bash` is a descendant of the old `bash` (where the function has been exported). E.g. if `gnome-terminal` inherits from the old `bash` and the new `bash` inherits from the `gnome-terminal`. This happens when the old `bash` runs in a terminal that is not `gnome-terminal`.

  My tests indicate if `gnome-terminal` runs from within `gnome-terminal` (so the environment contains `GNOME_TERMINAL_*` variables) then the new `gnome-terminal` process will delegate the task to the already running `gnome-terminal` and exit. The natural inheritance of the environment to the new `bash` cannot occur, still the new `gnome-terminal` process is smart enough to communicate not only the command but also the environment. This way the new `bash` inside the old `gnome-terminal` behaves like a descendant of the old `bash`, the exported function works. Tested with `gnome-terminal` 3.28.2.